# how to save gdb command result in a variable and reuse it again inside gdb?

Tags: linux, gdb, reverse-engineering, malware-detection

in GDB , i want to save the result of  `x/x $rsp` command ,  the value inside the address showing

example:
the result of the command

```
 x/x $rsp   is    0xffffaaaa : (0x00400b)
```

i want to save that address 0x00400b that i highlighted between brackets inside a variable ,
and reuse that variable that contain 0x00400b inside another GDB command.
example dump binary memory from that place when a breakpoint hits.

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you want like this:

```
(gdb) x/x $rsp
0x7fffffffb000: 0x004011e0
(gdb) set $foo=*((int*) $rsp)
(gdb) p/x $foo
$2 = 0x4011e0
```